# Angular JS scope.watch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following setup to watch an element and do something when it changes.  This cod is inside a custom directive - the fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/akcz3569/ with the full example:

```
  scope.$watch(
    function() {
      return $("#orgChartData").html();
    },
    function(oldval, newval) {
      console.log("Changed!");
    });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#orgChartData").append("<li>TEST</li>");
    console.log("TIMEOUT");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#orgChartData").append("<li>TEST</li>");
    console.log("TIMEOUT");
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#orgChartData").append("<li>TEST</li>");
    console.log("TIMEOUT");
  }, 6000);
```

My console says:

> > Changed!
> >
> > TIMEOUT
> >
> > TIMEOUT
> >
> > TIMEOUT

Why isn't this working?

Comment: There is no watch in demo. Why wouldn't you use angular data model to store data and render view instead of using jQuery?

Comment: Angular is particular. It's only going to "watch" changes that happen within it's scope (and setTimeout kicks off your function outside of angular's scope).  You'd probably need to call $scope.$apply() to get that to work.

Comment: @charlieftl - I just updated the fiddle, it has the correct version with the watch now.  I'm using JQuery because that's what the library I'm using uses.  I wrapped it in an Angular component, but it wants a nested `ul` to work with.

Comment: @bri - I'm in a directive, is that going to make a difference?